# Вызов методов в зависимости от значения ComboBox

Tags: c#, рефлексия

В коде есть много вычислений, в зависимости от начальных данных я получаю разный результат. Начальные данные определяются значением `ComboBox`, и в итоге в зависимости от этого, к переменной присваивается один из методов внешней библиотеке. Как лучше реализовать это? В итоге, думаю, в зависимости от `Combobox` приравнивать переменной `string` название метода в библиотеке и использовать `reflection`. И в коде, всё, что мне нужно будет менять, это перебор значений `Combobox` через switch и присваивание названия методов. Потому что в `ComboBox` в итоге будет значений 30-40. Нужно что-то универсальное и лаконичное.

Comment: Список методов заранее известен или вам сборку могут подкладывать с разным кол-вом методов? Иными словами он конечен или может меняться динамически?

Comment: Сгнатура у методов одинаковая?

Comment: @iluxa1810 сигнатура методов одинаковая. Список методов заранее известен. Будет лишь изменяется по мере заполнения внешней библиотеке.

Сборку внешнюю пишу я сам

Comment: А связывание позднее или ты на этапе компиляции можешь можешь уже знать все методы?

Comment: @iluxa1810 как всё происходит, я заполняю библиотеку, далее в основном коде нужно прописать новое значение в combobox и добавить к этому название новой функции, которая при данном значении будет вызываться. И заново компилировать программу.

Comment: @Fresto: То есть у вас ограниченное количество методов? Это методы одного класса?

Comment: @VladD Да, у меня есть внешняя библиотека, состоящая из разных методов. Все они имеют одну и ту же сигнатуру, возвращают один и тот же тип данных, но имеют разный расчет для этого типа. В основной программе мне нужно лишь вызвать один из методов данной библиотеки, в зависимости от выбранного значения combobox. По сути, дальше я буду просто наполнять библиотеку новыми методами, добавлять в combobox новое значение с этим методом и заново компилировать программу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Заведите интерфейс:

```
public interface IOperation
{
    int Execute(int p1, int p2);
}
```

Вместо статических методов создайте классы, реализующие его:

```
public class AddOperation : IOperation
{
    public int Execute(int p1, int p2)
    {
        return p1 + p2;
    }
}

public class MulOperation : IOperation
{
    public int Execute(int p1, int p2)
    {
        return p1 * p2;
    }
}
```

Тогда, получить список классов, реализующих заданный интерфейс можно примерно так:

```
var operationTypes =
    typeof(Program)
        .Assembly.GetTypes()
        .Where(t => t.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(IOperation)))
        .ToList();
```

Потом, после выбора нужной операции, создаем ее экземпляр и запускаем:

```
var operation = (IOperation)Activator.CreateInstance(operationTypes[0]);
Console.WriteLine(operation.Execute(1, 2));
```

Минус этого подхода (как по мне - незначительный) - эти классы с операциями должны иметь конструктор без параметров.

---

Другой способ - через рефлексию получить все методы класса/сборки, для того чтобы нужные методы отличить от других можно завести кастомный атрибут:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class ExecuteAttribute : Attribute { }
```

Помечаем нужные методы атрибутом:

```
public static class Library
{
    [Execute]
    public static int SumOperation(int p1, int p2)
    {
        return p1 + p2;
    }

    [Execute]
    public static int MulOperation(int p1, int p2)
    {
        return p1 * p2;
    }
}
```

Получаем список:

```
var methods = 
    typeof(Library)
        .GetMethods()
        .Where(m => m.GetCustomAttribute<ExecuteAttribute>() != null)
        .ToList();
```

Вызываем нужный:

```
Console.WriteLine((int)methods[0].Invoke(null, new object[] { 1, 2 }));
```

Минус этого похода - нет защиты от того, что у метода может быть другая сигнатура и это приведет к ошибке во время исполнения.

При желании в атрибуте можно сделать свойство для указания наименования метода:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class ExecuteAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string Name { get; }
    public ExecuteAttribute(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

Тогда, получить имя можно будет так:

```
var method = methods[0];
string name = method.GetCustomAttribute<ExecuteAttribute>().Name;
```

А задавать: `[Execute("Сложить")]`

Ну и для удобства вызова метода можно создать на его основе делегат (спасибо @VladD за подсказку):

```
var operation = (Func<int, int, int>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<int, int, int>), method);
Console.WriteLine($"{name} 1 и 2 будет {operation(1, 2)}");
```

Comment: О, вот с атрибутом — это хорошо. А то кто его знает, какие вспомогательные методы случайно имеют ту же сигнатуру?

Comment: хм, 2 вариант более компактный, чем создавать 40+ классов в итоге, спасибо, попробую оба варианта в итоге из двух ответов в итоге)

Comment: @VladD, ну мне не нравится только, что метод потом через рефлексию неудобно вызывать, ну и защиты нет от того, что пометим не тот метод случайно

Comment: Сигнатуру метода по идее можно проверять через рефлексию. И создать сразу делегат, который и вызывать.

Comment: @Fresto, ну да, сделаете атрибут с параметром и можно будет задавать методу имя, например: `[Execute("Сложить")]`

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53cz7sc6(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Ну, кстати, данный способ будет интереснее тем, что я в итоге не буду в основной программе каждый раз прописывать новые методы, а Combobox будет сам вызывать нужный метод по индексу в списке. Ведь methods будет иметь при вызове программе весь список методов библиотеки.

Comment: Я отпишусь, как проверю данный код, если будут еще вопросы

Comment: @VladD, а для проверки сигнатуры можно сделать юнит-тест. Да, создать делегат - это было бы приятно, хорошая идея

Comment: Так, проверил, всё прекрасно, как раз то, что мне и нужно, спасибо) Спасибо @VladD за ваш ответ тоже, просто тут более лаконично написано, ну, как по мне, правда много неизвестного ранее, буду изучать всё.

Comment: @Fresto, от себя рекомендую почитать Албахари - очень хорошо описана BCL, ее классы и методы

Comment: @Андрей хм, спасибо, обязательно начну изучать)

Answer (score 3):

Я бы сделал такую структуру данных:

```
public class MethodDescription
{
    public string Name { get; }
    public Action Method { get; }

    public MethodDescription(string name, Action method)
    {
        Name = name;
        Method = method;
    }
}
```

Теперь, раз внешняя сборка в ваших руках, она может легко предоставить список всех нужных методов. Например, так:

```
public static class Methods
{
    public static IEnumerable<MethodDescription> All { get; } =
        new[]
        {
            new MethodDescription("First", MyClass.First),
            new MethodDescription("Second", MyClass.Second),
            new MethodDescription("Very big", MyClass.VeryBig),
            new MethodDescription("Not at all", MyClass.NotAtAll)
            // добавляйте сюда ещё
        };
}
```

и так далее. Можно также собирать методы не вручную, а через рефлексию.

На клиентской стороне всё получается просто:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static extAssembly:Methods.All}}"
          DisplayMemberName="Name"/>
```

Comment: Хм, откуда вы знаете, что на клиентской стороне WPF?

Comment: @Андрей: Профессиональная деформация :)

Comment: Получается, мой класс с методами статический, ваш код я прописываю у себя в основной программе. А что на счет передачи параметров в метод?

Comment: @Fresto, вместо `Action` используйте подходящий тип, например: `Action<int, int>` или `Func<int, int, int>`

Comment: Может, словарь? Вызывать удобнее.

Comment: @Vlad на счет разных реализаций, я пока имею уровень, что прописываю первый подходящий, более менее лаконичный вариант и только потом уже думаю, как оптимизировать)

Comment: @Vlad: Можно и так. Но привязываться удобно по мнемоническому имени, а не по `Key`.

Comment: @VladD, не привязывался к словарям. А чем удобнее? По идее должен быть Binding на Keys и SelectedItem к строковому свойству Vm. Вроде все. Т.е. `<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static extAssembly:Methods.All}}" SelectedItem="{Binding Vm.Item}" />` Или я что-то упускаю?

Comment: @Vlad: Вопрос скорее не в удобстве программирования, а в мнемоническом имени. Если привязываться к кастомной структуре, то у нас поле с именем называется как мы хотим. А если `Dictionary<,>`, то только `Key` или `Value`. Удобно для пользователя, не нужно думать.