# Зачем нужны атрибуты для параметров, если есть рефлексия?

Tags: c#, .net, метапрограммирование

С другими типами атрибутов все ясно: можно с помощью рефлексии находить интересующие нас члены классов и сами классы, а потом делать различные вещи над ними.

А вот для чего нужны атрибуты для параметров методов? Я знаю, что есть некоторые полезные атрибуты, которые, например, позволяют получить имя откуда тот или иной метод вызывался (`CallerMemberNameAttribute`), что полезно для `MVVM`.

Получается, что они больше для компилятора нужны? Например, я не могу представить сценариев, когда они могли бы понадобится в других случаях, так как всю интересующую информацию можно получить через рефлексию.

Comment: Какую именно интересующую информацию вы можете получить через рефлексию, и почему вы думаете, что вся остальная информация никому не интересна?

Comment: @PavelMayorov, поэтому я спрашиваю, для чего мне может понадобится вешать атрибуты на аргументы метода. Вроде, типы аргументов через рефлексию получаются, передается ли параметр по ссылке или по значению, тоже получить. Вроде, большего и не надо. А фильтровать методы можно, повесив атрибут на уровне метода.

Comment: Давайте пойдем от обратного и немного ограничим вопрос, давайте допустим что MVVM нам нельзя добавлять атрибуты. Тогда нам нужны дополнительные методы, которые будут указывать как проверять данные, как их перерисовывать (или еще хуже, делать это руками в процессе отладки), тогда это удобство отрисовки и проверки данных. Теперь расширив задачу, можно сказать что атрибуты позволяют сократить объем написанного кода, сделав его удобным для чтения, и более гибким для расширения. Таким образом можно говорить что атрибуты это некий синтаксический сахар.

Comment: @Monomax, ну я не принижаю атрибуты в общем и их смысл мне понятен. Меня интересует юзабилити атрибутов, которые можно вешать, на параметры методов. Меня в общем то интересует есть ли от них какой-то прок в реальных сценариях или все ограничивается системными атрибутами для компилирования. Вот.

Comment: Разумеется речь идет об пользовательских атрибутах, которые можно повесить на параметр метода. Со стандартными все ясно, так как компилятор с помощью них, например, может взаимодействовать с неуправляемым кодом.

Comment: @iluxa1810 Смысл будет при прикладном использовании, например при использовании структуры, в которой вы укажите поля, а в атрибутах пометите, какие имена должны отображаться по умолчанию и необходимость их проверки на заполнение [загуглился хороший пример с хабра] (https://habr.com/post/140842/), фактически там пояснен пример приведенный мной выше.

Comment: В голову приходит следующий кейс, в котором может оказаться удобным и полезным использование *своих* атрибутов на параметрах методов: если вы пишете какой-то фреймворк, который может запускать код из методов, предоставляемых сторонними разработчиками (система плагинов какая-то, например), то они могут, например с помощью атрибутов предоставлять информацию для валидации. Пример возьмем из этого ответа: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/761498/218063, если добавить метод `DivideOperation`, то мы можем с помощью атрибута указать что второй параметр не может быть равен нулю

Comment: `[NotEqual(0, Error = "Делитель не может быть равен нулю!")]` и проверять данные еще до запуска, избегая выбрасывания и отлова исключений

Answer (score 7):

В атрибутах параметров, так же как и в любых других атрибутах, передается любая метаинформация которую нужно с этим самым атрибутом связать. А именно:

Служебная информация для компилятора, которую вешает сам компилятор:

- тип данных dynamic реализуется как `object` с атрибутом `DynamicAttribute`;
- именованные кортежи реализуются как `ValueTuple` с атрибутом `TupleElementNamesAttribute`;

Служебная информация для компилятора, которую может добавить пользователь:

- `CallerFilePathAttribute` / `CallerMemberNameAttribute` / `CallerLineNumberAttribute`;

Служебная информация для рантайма, которую может добавить пользователь:

- атрибут `MarshalAsAttribute`;

Служебная информация для фреймворков, которую может добавить пользователь:

- атрибуты управления биндингом в ASP.NET: `CookieAttribute`, `FormAttribute`, `QueryStringAttribute` и др.;
- атрибуты управления биндингом в ASP.NET.MVC: `BindAttribute`, `ModelBinderAttribute`.

Answer (score 6):

Например, [указание неуправляемого типа при маршаллинге P/Invoke](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshalasattribute?view=netframework-4.7.2):

```
[DllImport("mylib.dll")]
public static extern void Foo([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] String bar);
```